Is there any API to transfer Crypto from my wallet to Metamask?
I am creating and iOS and Android app.
Is there any API which transfer crypto from my wallet to other users Metamask wallet ?
Also, API should tell if other user wallet address is valid or not.
Kindly, help !

To transfer Crypto from your wallet to a user's wallet, you will need to write a custom JS script that will use your metamask private key using a Web3 library like ethers.js or web3.js. Here's a basic example using ethers.js:
Prerequisites:

Node.js: Ensure you have Node.js installed.
ethers.js: Install ethers.js.
npm install ethers



Steps to Transfer MATIC:
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

// 1. Set up your provider (e.g., Infura, Alchemy, or a JSON-RPC provider)
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-rpc.com/");

// 2. Define your wallet private key
const privateKey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"; // Replace with your wallet's private key

// 3. Create a wallet instance
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

// 4. Define the dynamic function to transfer MATIC with address validation
async function sendMatic(recipientAddress, amountInMatic) {
    try {
        // Validate the recipient address
        if (!ethers.isAddress(recipientAddress)) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Ethereum address");
        }

        // Convert MATIC to Wei (smallest unit in MATIC)
        const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amountInMatic, "ether");

        // Create the transaction object
        const tx = {
            to: recipientAddress,
            value: amountInWei,
            // Optionally, you can set gasPrice and gasLimit:
            // gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'gwei'),
            // gasLimit: 21000,
        };

        // Sign and send the transaction
        const transactionResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
        console.log(`Transaction sent! Hash: ${transactionResponse.hash}`);

        // Wait for the transaction to be confirmed
        const receipt = await transactionResponse.wait();
        console.log("Transaction confirmed! Receipt:", receipt);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Transaction failed:", error.message);
    }
}

// 5. Example usage with dynamic address and amount
const recipientAddress = "RECIPIENT_WALLET_ADDRESS"; // Replace with the dynamic user address
const amountInMatic = "0.1"; // Replace with the dynamic amount in MATIC

sendMatic(recipientAddress, amountInMatic);

Note:

You can make an endpoint for it for further use.
You can add check valid address via this func: ethers.isAddress

